# Adding cache manifest

Tags: 7

I need to add cache manifest file just like below in my static markup:

```
<html manifest="my.manifest">
```

Is there any module to add this or custom way?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [HTML5 tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/html5_tools) it enables you to preprocess the HTML element for manifest insertion.

> HTML5 Tools is a module that allows Drupal sites to be built using
>   HTML5 ... smartly.
>
> One of our goals is to provide as much support for HTML5 markup in a
>   set of Tools provided by a module so that you can use this module with
>   any HTML5 theme you'd like.

Comment: Thanku @shawn , I have installed this module but I have not found anything related to cache manifest in configuration

Answer (score 0):

you can do by adding manifest value in html_attributes in hook_preprocess_html as mentioned below:

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['html_attributes_array'] = array(
    'manifest' => 'example.appcache',
  );
}
```

Comment: thanku @Adi, here `example.appcache` is my manifest file? and how should I display variable $html_attributes in my `<html>` tag?

Comment: you can replace it with my.manifest

Comment: now how can I theme manifest file?